Long term viability of a human population with super healing that causes female to male sequential hermaphrotism
This question starts with a conversation I had with friends about the implications of super healing ability of Marvel comics characters like Wolverine, Deadpool, Hulk, and more.  How would a person that got a big infusion of blood from Wolverine (as one example of many) heal?  Would they heal like they are at the time of the blood infusion? Or heal as a kind of clone of Wolverine?  The super healing cells in the blood of a super-powered human like Wolverine would be carrying the genetic material of Wolverine, not necessarily convey super healing ability to cells in the person receiving this infusion.
Consider further the implications of someone with super healing abilities conveying this ability to any children.  Should a woman be impregnated by someone like Wolverine or Deadpool there will be some cells that cross the barrier created by the placenta, and if these cells contain the ability to regrow limbs like that shown by Deadpool or Wolverine then that can have some serious implications for the woman.  The woman, which presumably has no protections against such super healing cells, could potentially wake up from a night with Wolverine in the body of their son.  This would be because the zygote created from the fertilized egg would rapidly divide, inevitably cross the placental barrier, then "heal" the woman into whatever the genes had as what was "right" for a healthy body.  There's a 50/50 chance the genes are male.  Even if the genes are female then our superhero goes to bed with a woman then wakes up with that same woman in the body of their daughter, potentially with different colored eyes and/or hair as evidence of the "inheritance" of this rapid healing ability.
Marvel gets around this thought experiment among my friends with it being canon that any inherited super powers will not manifest until puberty.  If we assume a rapid healing ability is present upon conception, and the rate of healing is more in line with our present understanding of biology, then that still carries an interesting problem with the inheritance of a gene carrying an enhanced healing capability such that it means people can regrow limbs lost in battle or an accident.  This can explain why placental animals don't have the same healing ability as animals that lay eggs, the healing creates a problem of propagating further.
If we assume this healing ability is shared among male and female then a couple will try having children until the woman "heals" as their son and no further mating can occur.  If we assume each male then seeks another woman as mates then in an isolated society the gene will die out as all potential mating pairs end up as males.  If this is a female only trait then the enhanced healing ability only results in women with near immortality as with each successful impregnation the woman "heals" into the body of their daughter, or giving birth to a son that lacks this enhanced healing gene.  In either case the gene dies out fairly quickly in isolation.
If the healing ability is only inherited by the sons then a woman could give birth to a daughter that lacks this healing ability, but would "heal" into the son of any man carrying this super healing gene that impregnated her.  This could propagate for some time, potentially indefinitely if the population with this enhanced healing ability had an effectively infinite supply of women from the outside.  The thinking is there would be a 50/50 chance of giving birth to a daughter or "healing" into what is genetically the son of the man that impregnated the woman.  That means on average there's one daughter per woman and one "son" in that the woman lives the rest of her life having the genes and reproductive ability of her son.  That means, in effect, 2 children per woman on the aggregate at most.  That's fine for maintaining a given population if no children are lost to disease or accidents, but gives no room for growth.  Studies show that women need to have on average 2.1 to 2.3 children to maintain a population since one child replaces the father, one the mother, and that fraction of a child makes up for those that do not reproduce because of accidents, war, diseases, genetic disorders, or something else.
Assume a character in this world has access to the best knowledge of biology for the time.  That this character is on the receiving end of such a "gene transfer" in that she starts as a woman then ends up as a man with long life.  Assume that she (as a woman in the body of her biological son) made a realization of this problem as Darwinian evolution and Mendelian inheritance became known in the later part of the 19th century.  She's a woman with a hate for men to the point that that wishes that no man is ever born again on Earth, and that women live long and healthy lives without ever having to raise another son.  Finding this gene means meeting her goals as she originally envisioned them but violate the spirit as it means most every woman will live the bulk of their adult lives as men.  Any woman that dies as a woman is someone that by chance never experienced a fertilized egg end up as male, or had such a fertilized egg have some genetic mutation that left her sterile but with the super healing gene and the outward appearance as a woman.  For examples on how that might work consider any of a number of genetic conditions that could end up with a female phenotype but male genotype.
The idea is that there is a village of sorts that consists of women that were orphans, runaways, or the daughters of men with this enhanced healing ability.  (Remember that to be an adult man with this healing ability means a near 100% probability of starting life as a female.)  The females that enter the village would be as foundlings to teens that would not know of what could come with marrying the men in the village, or entered this as adult women willingly with the knowledge that each attempt at bearing a child could result in her transformation into a male.  The consequence of every female entering this village is nearly inevitably ending up "inheriting" this gene and living out the bulk of their adult lives as a man.  Once this is known to the wider world there will be people seeking out people in this village for bone marrow transplants, or getting impregnated, so they can have crippling injuries and diseases cured, or simply live for something like 300 years.  If the problem of maintaining a sustainable population is not solved then this gene could spread to where the human race dies out as a bunch of old men with no women around to bear their children.
What kinds of treatments or medications would be available to allow for a bias towards daughters as children so that should this super healing gene be known widely it doesn't result in the end of the human race?
Assume a kind of alternative history that contains this gene in relative secrecy which is then widely known in the near future.  Is there an herbal tea or something that is known to people of the 1890s to 1950s that could induce twin births?  The technology of today could likely resolve this issue, but assume this problem was discovered decades ago and a main character of this world found something of a viable solution with the scientific knowledge of the Victorian era.  What might that solution be?
I envision this transformation from female to male to take years, something like 10 to 15 years.  In this time she'd experience a kind of "second childhood" and "second puberty" in having the cells spread through her body and she'd experience living as an adult woman then, as the transformation becomes beyond undeniable, having to learn how to live as a man. Depending on the personality of the woman this might be taken in stride or be some kind of horror.  Presumably as time passes this would become part of the culture and young girls would have some kind of education on what will come, and that will soften the blow to the psyche of seeing themselves turn from female to male.  Any "losses" due to an inability to accept this transformation only adds to the problem of maintaining a viable population.
I realize that's a long setup to the question but I wanted to differentiate this as something unique to similar questions posed in the past.

Which one's the question? Can you isolate it in bold. It would help with readability if it were quite a bit shorter too.

I put in bold the core question as requested.  I've seen similar questions on sequential hermaphrodism but I have a narrow interpretation on what that means and so I made what might be a lengthy explanation to differentiate my question from the other questions posed previously.

First, remove all references to Marvel characters - we only deal in your world, not 3rd party worlds.  Second, it seems that everything before the bolded question could be removed and all but the immediate paragraph after it.  As I understand it, the question is "In Victorian times what treatments or medications..."  Except that in the next paragraph you are asking about inducing twin births, which is not what the bolded question is asking about - are you looking for girl babies (single or multiple) or twins?  More editing required

@KerrAvon2055 I understand that more editing might be required but if I remove reference to Marvel characters then that could mean some explanation of the scope of healing ability in this new world under discussion.  I expect readers to be familiar with the Marvel universe which is why I use that as a kind of starting point.  Creating a bias for twins is one possible solution, there may be others.  I'm still forming this idea in my mind so I'm having difficulty in editing it down

To continue my thought above I'm considering the implications of what it means to have genetics that makes a man effectively immortal as shown in the Marvel Cinematic Universe. While the MCU movies shows men that are long lived, if not incapable of death, it does not show them having children. Well, maybe there's children but I haven't seen that movie yet. Even so there does not appear to be a consideration of what this means to the wider world. If people know that Captain America took a serum that gave him a lifespan of over 100 years then there will be considerable effort to replicate that.

If your question is a straightforward "With Victorian medical knowledge, how can people create a bias towards daughters (or twins) being born?" then what is the relevance of the superhero/immortality/regeneration aspect of the question at all?  All the additional fluff about regenerating superheroes has no relevance to the question, since we have no way to know how a magic supergene would interact with any Victorian or contemporary medical practice.

@KerrAvon2055 " what is the relevance of the superhero/immortality/regeneration aspect of the question at all? "  The relevance is that a failure to find a solution means the end of the human race.  Every person (with perhaps a small minority as exceptions) seeks to live as long as they can.  That desire for long life could include making sacrifices such as having few to no children and living in a body that is opposite of what they see as their "true" gender/sex.  A desire for this healing ability is now in opposition of a desire for children, which would be difficult choice for anyone.

Humanity dies out Victorian science isn't great, so if they just have victorian knowledge then they can't bias gender selection that well and humanity dies out fairly quickly.

My theory is that that in this alternate history World War One and World War Two brings an influx of orphaned girls and widowed young women that would be seeking a place that would take them in and offer some prospects of some modicum of a "normal" life.  That would delay the extinction of this community for something like 50 years but still leave them relatively isolated that they'd have to use Victorian Era technology to both remain in isolation and find a means to maintain a viable population.  Their unique genetics would be revealed in the near future and with that comes modern solutions.

In an addition to the comment above any Victorian Era solution would presumably still be viable in modern times.  If there's a medication or process that could shift the male/female ratio from 1/1 in the year 1900 to more like 2/3 then presumably that still works in the year 2050 because the basic rules of physics, biology, and chemistry would not change in that time.  It should not take much to shift the balance from a slow death to rapid expansion.

Whilst we appreciate that it has relevance to your story - but what relevance has it to the question? Editing the question down to bare-bones of what you need, rather than giving us every little background detail would be optimal here. Brevity, but still give us the gist.

@Escapeddentalpatient.  I'm willing to discuss how to pare this down to the "gist" of the background required for the question but I'm at a loss on how.  I'd take this to a chat room but I'm not sure how that works.

The set-up for your question seems like it should be a separate question. I'm having a hard time seeing a woman turning into her unborn child because it has super healing as a hard science scenario. Horizontal gene transfer in real life only transfers a trait or so, not the entire genome. If that's essential for your story, fine, but I'd suggest breaking it off from this question and asking for a hard science reason it would happen that way.

How old is the Immortality Mutation? If it is ancient enough, then evolutionary pressure would cause at least some population to be fully, or partially immune to it, since Mortals would breed faster than Immortals, and have more chances to compete. If some people are immune to the Immortality Effect, even if the immunity is a recessive gene, then population would stabilize, with every once in a while some woman being born a mortal with a long fertility window.

" How old is the Immortality Mutation? "  At least a few hundred years by the time the main character discovers it.  Long enough that a kind of mythology develops about an "immortal queen" that lives in some remote part of the world, or at least "remote" for Europeans around about 1750, give or take a few decades to make the timeline work out.

" evolutionary pressure would cause at least some population to be fully, or partially immune to it "   Indeed.  A gene that grants super healing as I described it would be beneficial on the short term but detrimental long term.  As explained above the super healing gene would die out in one generation if women inherited it, but could last for many generations if only men inherited it.  If a population of humans has one man with this gene in it, and over many generations it spreads, then at some point the population dies out.  An "immortal queen" could exist but the gene dies with her.

Test tube babies with surrogacy. Medical techniques such as that can create any population that can get away with survival in the culture. Why wouldn't an immortal population (of any size) accrue the wealth, equipment, assistance and skills to perpetuate themselves?

Frame Challenge
How is this functionally different from Menopause?
(Quickly ducks from all the hormonally thrown objects at my general direction)
Hear me out for a second - Currently Women get their first period in their early teens (or earlier...) so lets say age 12, they are Fertile until about 45-55. With a realistic period of peak fertility between about 16-30
a 15 year period.
Assuming that the person who undergoes this transformation into a Man retains the ability to carry a child until the later stages of this process - All you have done is created an artificial Menopause - e.g. you have a window of fertility, then afterwards the individual can no longer bear children.
So my answer is: This changes very little because all women loose the ability to have children via a natural process - the only difference is the time frame - and given the time period (where marrying young and having large families was the norm) - I do not think the scenario you are worried about would come to fruition.

" How is this functionally different from Menopause? "  It's different in that after the transformation into a male the person is capable of transferring these genes to many other women to spread the genes that grant long life.  As an example of how this differs from a woman becoming infertile with age consider that Genghis Khan is suspected to have fathered more than 1000 children.  A man that carries the genes for long life could transfer them to potentially thousands of women willing to be on the receiving end of such a transaction before dying at the age of 409 years or whatever.

@MacGuffin And? Are you saying that Menopause is not passed on by Genes? I know what you mean - But unless you are saying that this gene starts from the moment they are born (and if I read correctly, it starts after puberty) all I am seeing is just a shortened window before Menopause - which doesn't have a big impact at all.

I'll add that the trend for large families doesn't change the issue. With each impregnation there's a 50% chance of the woman giving birth to a daughter, 50% chance of the X chromosome meeting the Y chromosome that carries this super healing gene and the woman doesn't give birth to a son but instead has the cells of her son implant in her body and she "heals" into her own son.  That means even if there's an acceptance of the potential for a large family the husbands/fathers with these genes will have on average one daughter and see his wife transform into his son.  That's 2 "children" at most.

" (and if I read correctly, it starts after puberty) "  It doesn't start after puberty, it starts after being impregnated with an XY zygote of a man carrying this super healing gene.  If the zygote is XX then there's a daughter born.  If the zygote is XY then the super healing gene prevents birth of a son, instead the cell divides and spreads through the woman's body to "heal" her body into what is effectively her own son.  She'd have something like a decade of a transition as the cells spread through her body and in the end she comes out as an adult male capable of impregnating other women.
